# Sorting a matrix by rows in java

Tags: java

I have to get a matrix with rows sorted (descending) like [sortrows function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html) in matlab.

```
A =
    95    45    92    41    13     1    84
    95     7    73    89    20    74    52
    95     7    73     5    19    44    20
    95     7    40    35    60    93    67
    76    61    93    81    27    46    83
    76    79    91     0    19    41     1
```

to

```
B =
    76    61    93    81    27    46    83
    76    79    91     0    19    41     1
    95     7    40    35    60    93    67
    95     7    73     5    19    44    20
    95     7    73    89    20    74    52
    95    45    92    41    13     1    84
```

I am using [JAMA](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/) which not contains a method like sortrows in matlab.
Which is the fastest way of doing this?

Comment: Transpose the matrices and sort by rows instead, then transpose again and you'll have sorted columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to sort rows from last column to first:

```
int n = A.length;

for (int c = n - 1; c >= 0; c--) {
   // bubble sort
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (int j = i; j < n ;j++) {
         if (A[i][c] < A[j][c]) {
            SWAP(A[i], A[j]); // swap the whole row
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Time Complexity = O(n * O(sorting algo))

Answer (score 1):

Well if you have a row such as

```
A = 95 45 92 41 13 1 84 95 7 73 89 20 74 52 95 7 73 5 19 44 20 95 7 40 35 60 93 67 76 61 93 81 27 46 83 76 79 91 0 19 41 1
```

and you need to sort it to

```
B = 76 61 93 81 27 46 83 76 79 91 0 19 41 1 95 7 40 35 60 93 67 95 7 73 5 19 44 20 95 7 73 89 20 74 52 95 45 92 41 13 1 84
```

You could probably write

```
A = B;
```

Would this be an acceptable solution? Could you still get an 'A' by doing that?

#[codetrolling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/16226/i-need-a-program-where-the-user-inputs-an-array-of-doubles-and-the-program-outpu)

Comment: Please click the link regarding code trolling

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what Jama is, but if your data is stored in a 2 Dimension array then you can use the [Column Comparator](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/16/column-comparator/) to sort the data on any column.